# Smooth animation when ember view is inserted/removed from DOM

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I use many custom views in my Ember app, that are dynamically inserted or removed from the DOM.

Everything works fine, except that I would like to use a smooth jquery animation when a view is inserted or removed. For example, I have this view:

```
<div id="container">
    {{#if App.slideShow}}
        {{view App.SlideShowView}}
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Normally container's height is 0px, and it changes adapting to the view's height; but when the view is inserted, it happens suddenly. I would like something like:

```
$('#container').slideDown(300);
//now the view should became visible
```

and when the view is removed i would like something like:

```
//the view becomes invisble
$('#container').slideUp(300);
```

What is the best way to set up this kind of animations in Ember?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was easier than what i thought initially;
it is sufficient to animate the outer wrapping div (container) instead of animating the view itself

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    var that = this;
    $('#container').animate({height: 364}, 300, function(){
        that.activateSlide();  //call method to activate jquery plugin
    });

},
willDestroyElement: function() {
    $('#container').animate({height: 0}, 300);
}
```

In this way the "container"'s dimensions are not conditioned if the view is or isn't in the DOM;
Thanks for suggesting the ember-animated-outlet plugin, seems a good work even if i believe is not useful for this task in particular; in any case i prefer the above solution because is lightweight...

Comment: using JQuery's animate inside `willDestroyElement` will not work, though. it's async and `destroyElement` only waits for `willDestroyElement` to finish.

Comment: Yes, it's async, but since container's dimensions are not conditioned if the view is or isn't in the DOM, when willDestroyElement fires, the animation it's executed; it does not matter if the view is removed before the animation end or not;

Comment: oh, yeah. makes sense after re-reading. I was trying to find a solution that works for `this.$()` too.

Comment: Where did you add this code? In Application controller? or I have to add it with all components? also does predefined height works for all cases or I have to calculate the height?

Answer (score 0):

In `App.SlideShowView` you can use the `didInsertElement` and `willDestroyElement` hooks to trigger animations.  You'd probably want to trigger animation on the main DOM element of the view.

```
App.SlideShowView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this.$().slideDown(300);
  },
  willDestroyElement : function(){
    this.$().slideUp(300);
  }
});
```

Another option is Ember Animated Outlet, but it's really aimed at animating transitions from route to route.  It seems like you're not really doing this "The Ember Way", so it might not be a good fit for you.

https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet

Comment: Have you tested this one? I doubt that the remove animation will work. It will start the animation on the DOM element, but Ember will destroy the DOM element before the animation is finished.

Comment: Yes, as mavilein says, it doesn't work; the slideDown animation is executed when the view is already rendered and so is useless; the same for slideUp, that is executed after the view is destroyed..

Answer (score -1):

The view rendering at the moment isn't assync, so you can have some problems like: css transitions on removed objects, because css transitions are assync. I recommend you to use the [ember-animated-outlet](https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet). And change your template to use an `animatedOutlet` instead of a conditional.

I hope it helps